# How can I save the visibility state of SoftPhone

Tags: javascript, api, cti

We can invoke `sforce.interaction.setVisible` - this is a [standard](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_setvisible.htm) CTI API method for expanding/collapsing SoftPhone in the Salesforce console.

My question is - how can I detect that SoftPhone was expanded/collapsed non-programmatically. Do we have an event we can listen to?

The problem I'm trying to solve is sort of save the state of SoftPhone to restore it after refresh.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a documented event, but maybe polling with the [sforce.interaction.isVisible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_isvisible.htm) function would be good enough?

```
(function poll() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        sforce.interaction.isVisible(function (response) {
           if (response.result) {
              console.log('SoftPhone is visible');
           } else {
              console.log('SoftPhone is not visible');
           }
           poll();
        });
    }, 5000);
})();
```